# Gmail apps script reading mailer-daemon messages

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I would like to scan all my emails in Gmail, and extract only the mailer-daemon messages (to identify rejected email addresses).

When I'm using these methods, None of the mailer-daemon messages are returned - only the "valid" messages:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1e29xgV1UU63SJEwF2aWQpWpcXMxyiylwEMGbuvbwADw");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Addresses");

  var row     = 1;

  sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue("Email Addresses");
  row++;

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
 for (var j = 0 ; j < messages.length; j++) {
   var txtBody = messages[i].getPlainBody();
   var txtSender = messages[i].getFrom();

   sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(txtBody);
   sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(txtSender);
   row++;
 }

 }
```

What can I use to process the mailer-daemon messages from the Mail Delivery Subsystem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should match the FROM: field of the message, something like:

```
var txtSender = messages[i].getFrom();

if (txtSender.indexOf("mailer-daemon") !== -1) {
   // Log the entry in the spreadsheet
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit.
I was also using the variable "i" instead of "j" in the messages array...

Answer (score 1):

You should be filtering threads from the query itself, its more optimal (also paged).

```
  function getBounced() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Bounced Addresses");

  var row = 1;
  var regExp = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}/i // "i" is for case insensitive

  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"mailer-daemon" subject:(failure|undeliverable)', 0, 50);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);

    for (var j = 0 ; j < messages.length; j++) {

      var txtSubject = messages[j].getSubject();
      var txtBody = messages[j].getBody();
      var bouncedEmail = regExp.exec(txtBody)[0];

      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(bouncedEmail);
      sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(txtSubject);
      row++;
    }
  }
}
```

I also added a little code to extract the bounced/rejected email with a RegExp